# Haskell: parallel computation and the 'sequential property' of monads

Tags: haskell, monads, repa

I am confused about why the REPA function `computeP` packs its result in a monad. It has the following type signature.

```
computeP :: (Load r1 sh e, Target r2 e, Source r2 e, Monad m) =>
            Array r1 sh e -> m (Array r2 sh e)
```

In [this tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial#Maps.2C_zips.2C_filters_and_folds) it says

> The reason for this is that **monads give a well defined notion of sequence** and thus computeP enforces completion of parallel evaluation in a particular point of monadic computations.

Likewise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450157/3083982) on Stack Overflow states that

> The reason why parallel computation in Repa must be monadic has to do partially with lazyness, but mostly with Repa's inability to deal with nested parallelism. **Sequential property of a Monad** solves it for the most part[.]

### Questions

- What does having this 'sequential property' mean exactly?
- How does a monad enforce this?
- For the example of `computeP`: there is no constraint on which monad is used, so I could use the identity monad. Is it okay then to use the following function instead that just unpacks the monad, or will this give unexpected results because it lacks this sequential property? If it is okay, is there even a need to use a monad at all?

  ```
  import Data.Functor.Identity
  import Data.Array.Repa.Eval
  import Data.Array.Repa

  myComputeP :: (Load r1 sh e, Target r2 e, Source r2 e) => Array r1 sh e -> Array r2 sh e
  myComputeP = runIdentity . computeP
  ```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should focus on one question at a time.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I'm guessing you mean both the questions `What does having this 'sequential property' mean` and `why does computeP pack its result in a monad`. The latter is actually meant as an example of the former: I guess that computeP uses a monad because of this sequential property, but I would like some clarification of how this sequential property works exactly. Is that what you mean? If you can clarify, I would be more than willing to clarify the question or split it up in multiple questions.

Comment: Really it's the "will this work for any monad"/"monads are confusing hellppp" bit that seems to stray from the topic, at least for me. But I also think this is a decent question and the three subquestions communicate what you want to understand pretty well.

Comment: @luqui Okay, I get what you mean. The world doesn't need another "monads are confusing hellppp" question, and it wasn't my intention to let it seem that way. I guess I was hoping to find an answer that explains this sequential thing using my own intuition as a starting point, but it may stray from the real question. I will remove the last part of my question.

Comment: For the "will this work for any monad" bit: it's there to challenge the need for a monad here. I will clarify it the question.

Comment: @Safron Just FYI there is [massiv](https://github.com/lehins/massiv) that similar in spirit to Repa, but doesn't have the restriction from your question, so it is totally fine with nested parallelism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This monad constraint is a heuristic trick. It helps disciplined users to **avoid nested parallelism**, but does nothing against malicious or clueless users.

Nested parallelism is the situation where, while computing some array in parallel, you end up having to compute another array in parallel. Repa does not support it (the reason is not important), so it tries to avoid it.

The type of `computeP` helps ensure that parallel computations are done in sequence with each other, but it is far from airtight; it is merely a "best effort" abstraction.

> How does a monad enforce this?

Actually, `computeP` is only expected to work with monads whose bind `(>>=)` is strict in its first argument, so that in `u >>= k`, the function `k` will be applied only after `u` has been evaluated. Then if you use `computeP` with such a monad,

```hs
do w <- computeP v
   k w
```

it is guaranteed that the vector `w` is evaluated before it gets passed to `k`, which may safely perform other `computeP` operations.

- Examples of strict monads: `IO`, strict `State`, `Maybe`, `[]`.
- Examples of lazy monads: `Identity`, lazy `State`, `Reader`. (Lazy monads can be made strict, but not the other way around. In particular, you can define a strict identity monad if you want to do only Repa computations.)

To prevent nested parallelism, the type of `computeP` intentionally makes it cumbersome to use within operations that are likely to be done in parallel, such as `map :: (a -> b) -> Array _ _ a -> Array _ _ b` and `fromFunction :: sh -> (sh -> a) -> Array _ _ a`, which take non-monadic functions. One can still explicitly unwrap `computeP`, for example with `runIdentity` as you noticed: you can shoot yourself in the foot if you want, but it's on you to load the gun, point it down and pull the trigger.

---

Hopefully, that answers what is going on in Repa. What follows is a theoretical digression to answer this other question:

> What does having this 'sequential property' mean exactly?

Those quotations are quite handwavy. As I see it, the relation between "sequentiality" and "monads" is two-fold.

First, for many monads in Haskell, the definition of `(>>=)` naturally dictates an order of evaluation, typically because it immediately pattern-matches on the first argument. As explained earlier, that's what Repa relies on to enforce that `computeP` computations happen in sequence (and that's why it would break if you specialize it to `Identity`; it is not a strict monad). In the grand scheme of things, this is a rather minor detail of lazy evaluation, rather than anything proper to monads in general.

Second, one core idea of pure functional programming is first-class computations, with explicit definitions of effects and composition. In this case, the effect is the parallel evaluation of vectors, and the composition we care about is sequential composition. Monads provide a general model, or interface, for sequential composition. That's another part of the reason why monads help solve the problem of avoiding nested parallelism in Repa.

The point is not that monads have an inherently sequential aspect, but it is that sequential composition is inherently monadic: if you try to list general properties that you would expect from anything worthy of the name "sequential composition", you're likely to end up with properties that together are called "monad"; that's one of the points of Moggi's seminal paper "Notions of computation and monads".

"Monads" is not a magical concept, rather it's enormously general so that lots of things happen to be monads. After all, the main requirement is that there's an associative operation; that's a pretty reasonable assumption to make about sequential composition. (If, when you hear "associativity", you think "monoid" or "category", note that all of these concepts are unified under the umbrella of "monoid objects", so as far as "associativity" is concerned, they're all the same idea, just in different categories.)